# Looping through an array while adding the data to a string and finally returning it, a faster way?

Tags: ruby, string

Getting the customer's to_s method by looping through

Is there a Ruby idiom to write the code in 1 line (or shorter than 3 lines of code)?

```
def method
  string = ""
  @customers.each { |customer| string += customer.to_s + "\n" }
  string
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@customers.join("\n") + "\n"
```

`join` creates a string from an array by calling `to_s` on each element that is not already a string and inserting them into the new string separated by the parameter to `join` (in this case `\n`). Since your code also adds a `\n` at the end (and `join` does not), you need to add `+ "\n"` after the call to `join` to get the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like

```
@customers.join("\n")
```

Comment: that works too, as sepp2k has stated, that the last bit should have "\n" also, so i need to add "\n" at the end of the join. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Mostly for fun, and building off @sepp2k's answer:

```
"#{@customers.join "\n"}\n"
```

I quite like embedded string syntax, because it's easy to expand later if you want other header/footer text.